# How do I parse efficiently one to many relation in model objects?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have 1:n relationship in tables:

Table A
id, name, foo, bar

Table B
id, x, y, z, id_A

In my domain model each of the rows of table A is an object and contains a collection of B.

How do I parse this?

I could first do query for A and then, in the parsing loop, for each row do a query to B. But this looks not very efficient.

I also tried join query, but this adds a new row for each entry of B, and then I can't map each of these rows to 1 model object.

Is there maybe a query where I can "reduce" the extra rows of join to one aggregated result?

Looks like a standard case of relational databases, but I can't find information about it.

Thanks.

Comment: What code do you need? It's a concept question, I don't have any code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an embedded database such as SQLite, there is no client/server communication overhead, so it is actually feasible to execute lots of little queries like this:

```sql
SELECT id, x, y, z FROM TableB WHERE id_A = ?
```

If you really want to use a single query for the loading of all B subobjects, you could use *two* separate queries like this:

```sql
SELECT id,   name, foo, bar FROM TableA ORDER BY id;
SELECT id_A, id, x, y, z    FROM TableB ORDER BY id_A;
```

You would then step through the two cursors *in parallel*, and for each A record, collect all the B records with the same ID; the ORDER BY clauses ensure that you see them in the correct sequence:

```java
cursorA = db.query(...);
cursorB = db.query(...);
cursorB.moveToFirst();
while (cursorA.moveToNext()) {
    id = cursor.getInt(0);
    a = new ObjectA(id, ...);
    while (!cursorB.isAfterLast() &&
           cursorB.getInt(0) == id) {
        b = new ObjectB(...);
        a.addB(b);
        cursorB.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Please note that this is not likely to be much more efficient than doing a separate query for each A, because sorting all records on the `id_A` column is not much more efficient than doing many lookups on the same column. (However, without an index on that column, the lookups would be much slower than the sorting.)